# Parity function definition and intuition, characteristic function of a set.

Tags: intuition, characteristic-functions, parity, bit-strings

I have a question of two (and a half) parts relating to parity functions.
I) Pertaining to the definition of a parity function.
II) Pertaining to the intuition behind checking some specific functions' parity.

**I)** In this particular set of questions, the parity function is defined as ([image link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Cfh.png)):
Parity function $Pf(X)$ is equal to $1$ if an even number of inputs is $1$ (i.e the function being checked, further on $f(x)$, is even), and $-1$ otherwise.

This is not in line with the typical "Parity Bit" function which, unlike this one, returns "$1$" if the $f(x)$ is odd. I was wondering whether my case was a specific definition or a distinct widely known separate one.

**II)** I would like my intuition checked on the following exercise, if possible, explained why/where I was wrong.

> For which of these does the parity function return $1$ for? In other words, which of these are "even"?
>   The dimension of input is $n>1$.

**1) Function that returns the least-significant (right-most) bit of the argument.**

For a two-bit variable there's only one possible input where it returns a "$1$". Thus, this one is odd.

**2) Function that returns k-numbered bit of argument, where k is less than n.**

Same logic as previous case.

**3) const f(x) = 1**

There's $2^{(n-1)}$ possible inputs for every $n>2$, and there's an equal amount of possible outputs. The function is even.

**4) const f(x) = 0**

If you consider 0 an even number, then the logic from before applies.

5) **"Characteristic function of a set with the cardinality of 5"**

This seems to be referring to an indicator function. My understanding is limited, but it wouldn't seem like this is even.

6) **f(x)=1 only if x has an odd number of ones when written in binary**

For every n, half of the inputs have an odd number of ones, which is $2^{(n-2)}$. For $n=2$ this number is equal to $1$, so it's incorrect to generalize this function's evenness.

7) **f(x)=1 only if x has an even number of ones when written in binary**

For every n, half of the inputs have an even number of ones, which is $2^{(n-2)}$. For $n=2$ this number is equal to $1$, so it's incorrect to generalize this function's evenness.

Answer (score 1):

We define $\tilde x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\tilde x_i\in\mathbb{Z_2}$ (is a bit-value),

and $\tilde x_i = 1-2x_i$ is clearly represented like the following function:

\begin{align*}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $x$ = 0}\\
-1 &\text{if $x$ = 1}
\end{cases}\end{align*}

When $x$ (the input bit) is equal to $0$ the function returns $1$, else if $x$ is equal to $1$ the function returns $-1$.

The length of the bitstream of $\tilde x$ can be calculated this way:
$$N = \lfloor\log_2{\tilde x}\rfloor+1$$

The parity function is defined as
\begin{align*}
P(\tilde x)=\prod_{i=0}^{N-1}f(\tilde x_i),
\end{align*}

The capital pi symbol represents multiplication of successive values. Hence, we multiply together all the parities. And since $f(x)$ returns either $1$ or $-1$ then $P(\tilde x)$ will return either the value $-1$ or the value $1$. The proccess of $P$ is iterative, and the value $-1$ is never changed unless a successive parity is also $-1$ (then it changes its sign), this parity will flip as many times as there are one's in the binary expansion (of $\tilde x$) and keep the final state when $i=N-1$. The final state depends on the number of $1$'s in the binary expansion basically. In short, everytime $\tilde x_i=1$ the product will change its sign, but when $\tilde x_i=0$ the product will do nothing to the result. These two series of actions can easily be understood when $x\cdot -1=-x$ and $x\cdot 1=x$. i.e.:

$$+\cdot+ = +$$
$$+\cdot- = -$$
$$-\cdot+ = -$$
$$-\cdot- = +$$

From the above reasonings we can deduce some facts:

1. when $\tilde x$ has an odd number of $1$'s in its binary expansion, $P$ will return $-1$.
2. when $\tilde x$ has an even number of $1$'s in its binary expansion, $P$ will return $1$.

Examples:

$$P(2_{10}) = P(10_2) = -1$$
$$P(13_{10}) = P(1101_2) = -1$$
$$P(27_{10}) = P(11011_2) = 1$$
$$P(60_{10}) = P(111100_2) = 1$$

Other facts:

The bitlength itself do not influence the parity.

---

Answers:

**1) Function that returns the least-significant (right-most) bit of the argument.**

$$P(00_2) = 1$$
$$P(01_2) = -1$$
$$P(10_2) = -1$$
$$P(11_2) = 1$$

There are two possible inputs where it returns a $1$: $0$ and $3_{10}$.

**2) Function that returns k-numbered bit of argument, where k is less than n.**

Im not sure what you mean by k-numbered bit of argument. Assuming you mean the bitlength of the argument, this does not influence the output parity.

**3) const f(x) = 1**

The function is only even when $\tilde x = 0$ or there is an even number of $1$'s in the binary expansion of $\tilde x$.

**4) const f(x) = 0**

$0=$ parity $1$

**5) "Characteristic function of a set with the cardinality of 5"**

Assuming you mean the parity $1$ is even, then $5$ is even.

**6) f(x)=1 only if x has an odd number of ones when written in binary**

False, $P(\tilde x)=-1$ if there is an odd number of ones.

**7) f(x)=1 only if x has an even number of ones when written in binary**

True, $P(\tilde x)=1$ if there is an even number of ones.